# Projeto Laravel não reconhece meu arquivo Javascript

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Essa é a estrutura do meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vocês podem ver na imagem acima o arquivo app.js está na pasta **assets/js**

meu arquivo app.js está assim;

```
//var urlUsers = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10';
        var urlUsers = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
        new Vue({
            el: '#main',
            created: function() {
                this.getUsers();
            },
            data: {
                lists: []
            },
            methods: {
                getUsers: function() {
                    axios.get(urlUsers).then(response => {
                        this.lists = response.data
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

O arquivo para configurar os arquivos Javascript no projeto Laravel é o **webpack.mix.js**

Ele está assim;

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js([
  'resources/assets/js/vue.js',
  'resources/assets/js/axios.js',
  'resources/assets/js/app.js',
], 'public/css/app.js');
```

E a pagina principal está assim;

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel e Vue</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>
          <div id="main" class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <h1>VUEjs - AJAX axios</h1>
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li v-for="item in lists" class="list-group-item">
                                    @{{ item.name }}
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <h1>JSON</h1>
                            <pre>
                                @{{ $data }}
                            </pre>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Meu browser era para aparece assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas está aparecendo assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque será que meu projeto não está reconhecendo os arquivos Javascript ou é porque o arquivo app.js está com erro de lógica de programação?

================================================================

Esse é meu repositório:

[Clique aqui para acessar o repositório](https://github.com/wladyband/laravel-vue-crud)

Essa é a imagem que aparece no log do consoles PowerShell

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E estou seguindo esse curso aqui no youtube.

[Clique aqui para ver a vídeo aula.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EKLN_1mNW8&lc=z22oz3a43sa4tlbax04t1aokgba4kmezuc1xun3pmuwxrk0h00410.1507568439397065&feature=em-comments)

======================================================

está gerando esse erro;

```
PS C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\wladimi
r\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud\artisan on line 18

Warning: require(C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\wladimir\Des
ktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
 C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud\artisan on line 18

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\U
sers\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud\artisan on line 18
PS C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud> php artisan serve
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\wladimi
r\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud\artisan on line 18

Warning: require(C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\wladimir\Des
ktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
 C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud\artisan on line 18

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\U
sers\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud\artisan on line 18
PS C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-vue-crud-master\laravel-vue-crud>
```

Comment: Tens algum erro na consola?

Comment: Onde é defenida no Laravel a pasta root/public do cliente?

Comment: Não aparece mensagens de erro no console do Google Chrome, a pasta está definida como sendo o assets/js   quero pedir desculpas se de repente minha resposta não é compatível com a pergunta, é porque eu comecei a estudar PHP Laravel a pouco tempo.

Comment: Por favor visualize novamente minha postagem, pois eu fiz atualizações.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está especificando um caminho incorreto dentro do seu arquivo **webpack.mix.js**:

O seu arquivo está assim:

```
mix.js([
  'resources/assets/js/vue.js',
  'resources/assets/js/axios.js',
  'resources/assets/js/app.js',
], 'public/css/app.js');
```

Perceba que na última linha você coloca o app.js dentro da pasta **css** e não **js** como você chama na sua página principal.

Comando certo:

```
mix.js([
  'resources/assets/js/vue.js',
  'resources/assets/js/axios.js',
  'resources/assets/js/app.js',
], 'public/js/app.js');
```

Depois disso você vai precisar importar o `vue` e o `axios` dentro do seu arquivo **resources/assets/js/app.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
```

Feito tudo isso execute o `npm run dev` novamente.

Comment: Saudação @JuniorNunes , mas ainda continuar com o problema.

Comment: @wladyband deu um `npm run` novamente?

Comment: Eu não estou usando o npm run, mas fiz assim, eu executei o npm run e depois executei o php artisan serve, e mesmo assim continuar com problema, tenho uma observação, quando executo no npm run dev ele não mostra nada, eu já tentei na porta 8000, 8006 e 8080, mas quando executo o php artisan serve ele me mostra pela porta 8000, mas é assim... ainda está com o mesmo problema.

Comment: será que você se incomodaria de baixar meu projeto e testar localmente? por favor.

Comment: @wladyband já identifiquei o problema e consegui rodar localmente, editei a resposta da uma olhada! Vou "comitar" as modificações que fiz.

Comment: Eu não sei extamente onde fez alteração, mas está gerando um erro ao tentar executar 'php artisan serve', eu fiz uma atualização na minha postagem poderia dá uma olhada por favor?

Comment: @wladyband certifique-se de rodar o `composer install` caso não tenha feito ou o `composer update` pra atualizar as dependências.